# Creating a C/C++ Console Project in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

The options included in Visual Studio for Mac Community Edition's project template dropdown only include C#, F#, IL, and VBNet. I am interested in creating a C/C++ console project, instead.

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio Community for Mac]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Visual Studio for Mac supports **only** **F#** and **C#**; please check [Visual Studio 2017 for Mac Platform Targeting and Compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-mac).

Comment: C++ support is on its way, and is currently a Google Summer of Code project, titled "Overhaul Xamarin Studio C/C++ Addin" https://summerofcode.withgoogle.com/organizations/5363112430534656/?sp-page=2#6538259587923968 It aims to revive the dead C/C++ addin, and let's see how it goes.